# Certain SSH shell script doesn't run well in Cisco APIC bash

Tags: cisco

The following ping script is running just fine in both script form and interactive shell

**ping-only.sh**

```
date
for i in 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.3 10.4.1.13
    do  echo -e "\nIP: $i"
    ping -c 1 $i | grep from
done
```

However, when I run the SSH shell script, it just stuck at the first host

**ssh-get-banner-only.sh**

```
date
for i in 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.3 10.4.1.13
    do  echo -e "\nIP: $i"
    timeout 1 ssh $i
done
```

Sample output

```
user@APIC> ./ssh-get-banner-only.sh
Mon May  6 04:43:24 UTC 2019

IP: 10.1.1.1
###############################################################
#                 Authorized access only!                     # 
###############################################################
```

It work just fine when I paste the same code manually to the shell

```
user@APIC> date
Mon May  6 04:36:33 UTC 2019
user@APIC> for i in 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.3 10.4.1.13
> do  echo -e "\nIP: $i"
> timeout 1 ssh $i
> done


IP: 10.1.1.1
###############################################################
#                 Authorized access only!                     # 
###############################################################

Password:

IP: 10.1.1.3
###############################################################
#                 Authorized access only!                     # 
###############################################################

Password:

IP: 10.4.1.13
###############################################################
#                 Authorized access only!                     # 
###############################################################

Password:
user@APIC>
```

Comment: Are you sure the same interpreter is used when executing the script manually vs executing your script? Try to find out the shell interpreter with `echo "$SHELL"` and then add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the first line of your script.

Comment: @waza-ari, `user@APIC:~> echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
user@APIC:~>`

Doesn't matter whether the shebang is there or not. Still getting the same output

Answer (score 0):

To address this issue, you can try modifying the script to use the -o ConnectTimeout option of the ssh command, which specifies the maximum time to wait for the SSH connection to be established. Here's an updated version of the script using this option:

```
#!/bin/bash

date
for i in 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.3 10.4.1.13; do
    echo -e "\nIP: $i"
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 $i "echo Connected"
done
```